# MSI installation: wrong shortcut's path after restarting

Tags: windows-installer, shortcut

Good morning,

I am having a problem when installing a msi package by using Group Policy Object (GPO). I have created the msi with Visual Studio 2010 and I have created the GPO in order to install the application in all the machines.

The fact is that the application is correctly installed and a shortcut is created in the User's Programs Menu. This shortcut points to:

```
C:/Program Files/my_application/
```

In that directory there are some config files that are necessary to use the application.

However, after restarting the computer, the aforementioned shortcut changes and it now points to:

```
C:/Program Files(x86)/my_application/
```

As this path does not exit in the computer, when I try to start the application I received an error saying that the configuration files are not found in the directory:

```
C:/Windows/system32/config
```

Of course, these config files are really stored in the directory:

```
C:/Program Files/my_application/config/
```

Anybody knows why the shortcut change its pointer to the new directory (x86) instead of keeping the original directory?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit application?  32-bit or 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has already been solved. The solution was to force the application to be installed in the `[windowsVolume]` (this is `C:/`) instead of the `[ProgramFilesFolder]`.

In this case the shortcuts are always pointing to:

```
'C:/my_application'
```

To build the installer the release option was set to "Any CPU" so the application can be installed in both 32 and 64 bits.

Thanks,

Comment: Not an ideal solution, since polluting the root directory is liable to make system administrators cross.